# How can I use CSS display: flex to position proportional widths?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using flex to position two divs:

I have two divs inside this container and if possible I would like to space them like this:

```
xxxxxxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxxxx
x         x     x         x
x   45%   x 10% x  45%    x
x         x     x         x
xxxxxxxxxxx     xxxxxxxxxxx
```

and then have them appear like this if there is not enough space:

```
xxxxxxxxxxx 
x         x  
x         x 
x         x 
xxxxxxxxxxx 

xxxxxxxxxxx 
x         x  
x         x 
x         x 
xxxxxxxxxxx
```

I tried to do this but it does not seem to work.

```
#city {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
}

<div id="city">
   <div style="flex-grow: 45;">xx</div>
   <div style="flex-grow: 10;"></div>
   <div style="flex-grow: 45;">yy</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone point me to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: i would do this way : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Eabovz , only using the basis flex display.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work for me.  I will leave the question open for a while to see if there are other possible solutions. Thanks for taking the time to come up with your suggestion.

Comment: There seems to be one confusing info about your problem: If you set your flex item's size in %, they'll always have that regardless of container size unless they also define `min-width` where wrapping would occur. **And** you also forgot to provide info about space between the items when they wrap into separate lines? Is it also somewhat 10%? If that's the case, have you considered media queries then where you'd define `flex-direction: row` when there's enough space and `flex-direction: column` when space is too narrow?

Answer (score -1):

In addition to GCyrillus' comment, I would also suggest to use syntax that supports other older browsers that is:

```
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
```